# smartGWT TileGrid::onKeyPress -- how to override Enter key, but keep default processing for other keys

Tags: smartgwt, onkeypress

I am loading file icons on a tile grid in a smartGWT project.  When Enter key is pressed, I want to open the selected file for display.

When I override the onKeyPress handler, it does work, but the tile grid navigational behavior using left/right/up/down arrow keys is lost.

My question is.., how to retain the default processing behavior, while still override the Enter key.

```
  tileGrid.addKeyPressHandler (new KeyPressHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onKeyPress(KeyPressEvent event) {
      if (EventHandler.getKey().equals("Enter")) {
       //do something special here
      }
      else {
        **//TODO: do the default processing..**.
      }
    }
  });
```

EDIT:

@Ras, here is the code that simulates the problem.

```
package com.rv.gwtsample.client;

import com.google.gwt.core.client.EntryPoint;
import com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT;
import com.smartgwt.client.data.Record;
import com.smartgwt.client.widgets.events.KeyPressEvent;
import com.smartgwt.client.widgets.events.KeyPressHandler;
import com.smartgwt.client.widgets.tile.TileGrid;
import com.smartgwt.client.widgets.tile.TileRecord;

/**
 * @author rvnath
 *
 */
public class MyTileGrid implements EntryPoint {

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see com.google.gwt.core.client.EntryPoint#onModuleLoad()
     */
    @Override
    public void onModuleLoad() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        TileGrid grid = new TileGrid();
        grid.setLeft(50);
        grid.setTop(50);
        grid.setWidth("300");
        grid.setHeight("200");
            DetailViewerField field = new DetailViewerField("Name");
        grid.setFields(field);
        grid.addKeyPressHandler(new KeyPressHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onKeyPress(KeyPressEvent event) {
                if (event.getKeyName().equals("Enter"))
                    GWT.log("Enter pressed");
            }
        });

    Record[] rec = new TileRecord[32];
    for (int i=0; i<32; ++i) {
        rec[i] = new TileRecord();
    }

    grid.setData(rec);
    grid.draw();
}

}
```

If I disable the onKeyPress handler, arrow keys can navigate between the elements of the tile grid.  If I enable, then the entire tile grid panel scrolls, instead of selection change.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of using KeyPressHandler, try the KeyDownHandler, it works.

```
        tileGrid.addKeyDownHandler(new KeyDownHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onKeyDown(KeyDownEvent event) {
                if (EventHandler.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase("Enter")){
                    openModal(tileGrid.getSelectedRecord());
                }
            }
        });
```

Tested with the latest 3.0 smartgwt build.

Answer (score 0):

@Mupparthy, I've also implemented **keyPressHandler()** for **TextAreaItem**. I also had the same requirement that only delete & backspace keys were needed to be handled. What I did is, don't handle the **else** part. It automatically did default processing for other keys including all the arrow keys. So if it's not working for you, provide me a stand alone code so that we can make it work.

Comment: Hi @RAS, I have added the code snippet.  Can you check n let me know, if this can be fixed.
thanks in advance...

Comment: @MupparthyRavindranath, Have you tried removing 'else' statement?

Comment: Hi @Ras,  There is no 'else' statement in the code.  Just an If for handling "Enter" key.